# SQL User defined function, can't find dbo or user-defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select, user-defined-functions

I have created a function in my database using this query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(MAX) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(MAX) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(MAX))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
GO
```

And SQL Server returned : `Command(s) completed successfully.`

Then I tried to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM maj_Posts a
WHERE FeedID = (SELECT dbo.fnSplit(b.FeedIDs) FROM maj_Magazines b WHERE OwnerID = 1)
ORDER BY countOfComments DESC
```

It returned an error: `Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnSplit", or the name is ambiguous.`

**Note that `b.FeedIDs` is an string contains comma-separated numbers, like this : `1,2,4`**

**And I want to get rows from `maj_Posts` which their `a.FeedID` is one of the numbers in `b.FeedIDs`...** (For example, if `b.FeedIDs` is `1,2,4`, I need rows from `maj_Posts` that their `FeedID` is 1 or 2 or 4.)

What is the problem?

Comment: You have created table valued function but you are using it as if it was scalar one.

Comment: I didn't get what you said. Can you explain more please?

Comment: This kind of functions belong to `FROM` clause.

Comment: I'm new to SQL Server user-defined functions, and I don't know which kind of function is right for me. Can you help me to fix this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this:

```
SELECT * FROM maj_Posts a
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.maj_Magazines b
ON 1 = 1 AND b.OwnerID = 1
OUTER APPLY dbo.fnSplit(b.FeedIDs, ',') AS s
WHERE a.FeedID = s.item
ORDER BY countOfComments DESC;
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM maj_Posts a
WHERE FeedID IN 
(
  SELECT item FROM maj_Magazines AS b
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplit(b.FeedIDs, ',') 
  WHERE b.OwnerID = 1
)
ORDER BY countOfComments DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! Both works. but it seems that optional argument in `fnSplit` didn't work, and I changed your codes to `dbo.fnSplit(b.FeedIDs,',')`. Can you explain why optional arguments are not working?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the delimiter. I can't tell you why optional parameters don't work in user-defined functions, I just know that they don't. You always need to pass all arguments (the only reason you would specify a default is to document what you expect the typical value to be).

Comment: Thank you. and your second SQL Query seems to be more understandable to me!

Comment: I don't understand what are these `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` do?

Comment: @Mahdi maybe these can help: http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3798361/Using-T-SQL-CROSS-APPLY-and-OUTER-APPLY.htm http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2010/12/11/cross-apply-outer-apply/

Answer (score 1):

```
USE [oberoi]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_AssetReport]    Script Date: 03/23/2013 12:27:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AssetReport]
AS


BEGIN
SELECT     distinct am.assetid,am.computerName,
 ao.os_name,ao.user_name,ao.reg_code, ao.reg_org, ao.reg_to,
 ao.localization,  ao.product_key,
-- an.ip_address,

   amem.physical_mem,amem.virtual_mem,(Select top 1 ip_address from Asset_Network where assetId=am.assetid) as ip_address,ap.processor_name,ap.speed,  ap.manufacturer,
   api.serial_number,api.product_name, api.product_manufacturer,am.TagNo,am.PONo,dbo.capacity_checkn(apd.capacity) as capacity,am.Location,am.AssetOwner,am.CompanyCode,am.PurchaseDate,am.AssetCategory,am.Remarks
FROM                  Asset_mst As am INNER JOIN
                     -- Asset_Network AS an ON am.assetId = an.assetId INNER JOIN
                      --Asset_Inventory As AI on an.assetId=AI.assetId INNER JOIN
                      Asset_OperatingSystem AS ao on am.assetId=ao.assetId JOIN
                      Asset_Memory AS amem ON ao.assetId = amem.assetId INNER JOIN
                      Asset_Processor AS ap ON amem.assetId = ap.assetId INNER JOIN
                      Asset_ProductInfo AS api ON ap.assetId = api.assetid INNER JOIN
                      Asset_PhysicalDrive AS apd ON am.assetId = apd.assetid 


where CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),Am.createdatetime )) = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),ao.inventory_date )) 
--And CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),an.inventory_date )) = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),AI.inventoryDate ))
--And CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),an.inventory_date )) = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),ao.inventory_date )) 
And 
CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),Ao.inventory_date )) = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),amem.inventory_date )) 
And CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),amem.inventory_date )) = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),ap.inventory_date ))
And CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),ap.inventory_date )) = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),api.inventory_date ))
And CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),api.inventory_date )) = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(char(12),apd.inventory_date ))
and am.Isdelete=0

enter code here

End
```